# how to deploy tizen tv application on emulator?

Tags: tizen-emulator

I'm a novice in tizen development.
When I run am app in the IDE emulator, the following message appears:

```
Launching AnalogicWatch has encountered a problem. 
java.io.IOException: Both an author and a first distributor must be required.
Please check your profile information.
```

How can I fill those parameters to make the app appear in the emulator?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to install the certificate extension in the Tizen IDE. you can get details procedure in the following link:

https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/issuing-tizen-certificate-certificate-extension-ver-1.1.1

Comment: If you think my answer is helpful for you, it would be nice to mark this as correct answer and with an upvote. :)